# need to make username:plain from hash:plain username:hash

Tags: linux, shell

File A contains `hash:plain` 
File B contains `username:hash`
needed output `username:plain`
Any way to do that in shell?

Answer (score 0):

Use command substitution with `cut`:

```
echo $(cut -d: -f1 B):$(cut -d: -f2 A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files aren't in the same order, that there are multiple lines per file, and you want lines with the same hash to be paired, a few ways:

```
$ join -11 -22 -t: -o 2.1,1.2 <(sort -k1,1 -t: filea) <(sort -k2,2 -t: fileb)
```

(Requires bash, zsh, ksh93, or another shell that understands `<()` redirection)

or

```
$ awk -F: -v OFS=: 'NR == FNR { hashes[$1] = $2; next }
                    $2 in hashes { print $1, hashes[$2] }' filea fileb
```